# Keep SVG proportions whilst reducing window (or container) size

Tags: html, svg, size, aspect-ratio

I have an SVG graphic that is the child element of a container.

If I want it to fit the full width of this container I normally do `preserveAspectRatio="none"` and set the width to 100% (with an optional height value if I want to add some extra height to the SVG).

However, I would like to have it so the SVG fits the container, but when I drag the window to a smaller size the wedge shape (i.e. diagonal angle of the SVG), stays at the same angle, whilst also still filling the container.

In the sample code I've kept the `preserveAspectRatio=none` code to show the general effect I would like (the difference being of course I would like the angle of the wedge to stay the same as the window is reduced in size).

Is this possible? I'm struggling to think of a way to get this to work.

Here is a Codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/pGbPby

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 10rem;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.wedge {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 4rem;
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg class="wedge" preserveAspectRatio="none" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 376.9 122.7">
    <polyline fill="#000" points="376.9 122.69 0 122.35 376.55 0 376.9 122.69"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You probably want a different value for preserveAspectRatio

Answer (score 0):

If you want the SVG to keep its aspect ratio, and not stretch, then don't use `preserveAspectRatio="none"`. Use a different `preserveAspectRatio` value. For example `"xMinYMax slice"`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 10rem;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.wedge {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 4rem;
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg class="wedge" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax slice" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 376.9 122.7">
    <polyline fill="#000" points="376.9 122.69 0 122.35 376.55 0 376.9 122.69"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

However you are obviously going to have to decide what you want to happen if the page gets wide enough that the wedge gets so tall that the top gets clipped off.  For example in your example (and in my example above) you have limited the height of the SVG to `4em`. So you are only seeing the bottom of the wedge.

If I change the SVG height to `100%`, you see more of it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 10rem;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.wedge {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg class="wedge" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax slice" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 376.9 122.7">
    <polyline fill="#000" points="376.9 122.69 0 122.35 376.55 0 376.9 122.69"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Of course, you may also want to reduce the angle of the wedge.